# Specific QGIS file will not open and "QGIS quit unexpectedly" screen pops up

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, error

This problem has occurred for me several times for different files and I can't figure out what the cause is. I will be working on a QGIS file for several weeks and then all of a sudden one day I can no longer open the file and the attached screen appears. I don't think the cause is missing shapefiles with broken links.
I've done some research and think I maybe need to open the file in a text editor, but I have no experience with this and don't know what part of the text I'm supposed to alter. I have been using QGIS 3.0 on a mac.

[image]

Comment: is the this on an Apple Mac?

Comment: You should upgrade to 3.4 - there's been many hundreds of fixes since 3.0